# Chinese movie with a semi blind/blind man

Tags: identify-this-movie

- A Chinese man who is blind somehow encounters this woman.
- All I remember vividly was that there was this scene that he was
  feeling an artwork that was replicating the woman's face using beans,
  so he can feel to "see" her face.
- There was also this scene where I think he got stabbed by something
  and he was able to see the woman who is just in front of him.
- I can't remember but I feel the movie does contain Chinese martial
  arts.
- The male character carries a wooden bag where I remembered there was
  a slit of some sort for him to drop his money into.

Forgive me for all the poor details, I don't remember much as I viewed it when I was really young. If this is of any help:

- I think I watched it back in 2005-2008

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the Hong Kong action comedy [The White Dragon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0441263/combined) from 2004.

> A teenage girl is given the martial arts skills of The White Dragon. When she discovers that the famed [blind] assassin, Chicken Feathers, is planning to kill her beloved prince, she seeks to prevent him.

It's all there. The blind man has a wooden money box on his back that people put coins in, he tries to depict the girl's face using food, and when she stabs him later on, he's suddenly able to see her. Here's the trailer: